# JavaScript question. I'm learning how for loops and arrays work alongside a method, not sure why I am getting a NAN message in my console

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, methods

So far, here is the code I have put together, followed by the errors I am getting.

```
var johnFamily;

johnFamily = {

    tipCalc: function() {

        var percentage;

        johnFamily.fullName = 'John Smith';

        johnFamily.bills = [124, 48, 268, 180, 42];

        johnFamily.tips = [];
        johnFamily.totalBills = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < johnFamily.bills.length; i++) {

            if (johnFamily.bills[i] < 50) {
                percentage = .2;
            } else if (johnFamily.bills[i] > 50 && johnFamily.bills[i] < 200) {
                percentage = .15;
            } else if (johnFamily.bills[i] > 200) {
                percentage = .1;
            } else {
                console.log(johnFamily.fullName + ' ' + 'did not leave a tip.');
            }

            johnFamily.tips[i] = johnFamily.bills * percentage;
            johnFamily.totalBills[i] = johnFamily.bills + johnFamily.bills * percentage;
        }
    }
};

johnFamily.tipCalc();
console.log(johnFamily);
```

But then, THIS is what I get when I log it to the console

```
tips: (5) [NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN]

totalBills: (5) ["124,48,268,180,42NaN", "124,48,268,180,42NaN", "124,48,268,180,42NaN", "124,48,268,180,42NaN", "124,48,268,180,42NaN"]
```

It should be creating new properties and adding values to them through the method.

Comment: `johnFamily.bills` is an array, should probably be `... = johnFamily.bills[i] ...;` at the end of your for loop

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem

```
johnFamily.bills * percentage;
```

`johnFamily.bills` is an array, and an array times a number doesn't make any sense, so you get `NaN`. You probably meant to do this, in order to calculate a specific time for a specific bill.

```
johnFamily.bills[i] * percentage;
```

Comment: thanks. so far, this is the only thing about the code that I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change the last two lines of the for loop to:

```
johnFamily.tips[i] = johnFamily.bills[i] * percentage;
johnFamily.totalBills[i] = johnFamily.bills[i] + johnFamily.bills[i] * percentage;
```

you were multiplying times the array johnFamily.bills instead of the number

Comment: thanks that fixed it. So, I was multiplying the value of percentage by 'tips' & 'bills' but I did not specify bills or tips at [i] position?